# solr php curl update command

Tags: php, curl, solr

Going off of this link [here](http://yonik.com/solr/atomic-updates/), I'm trying to update a record in my solr instance using PHP and cURL, but I'm somewhat unfamiliar with command line cURL so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost:8983/solr/database/update");

$data = array(
          "id" => "6686",
          "name" => array(
            "set" => "Brian")
          );

$data_string = json_encode($data);          

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Here is the error I'm getting - I'm sure "id" is a field in my solr instance:

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":2},"error":{"msg":"Unknown command 'id' at [5]","code":400}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to get value of data sent for check it right or wrong.

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")),1).'</pre>';
```

And use this code to replace

```
$data = array(
      "id" => "6686",
      "name" => array(
        "set" => "Brian")
      );                                                              
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8983/solr/database/update'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                     
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Hmm... this gives me the exact same output as I have above - and the 'print_r' does not print out anything.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of my original question was correct - just a few syntax issues it looks like.  The below code works to update a solr record using PHP and cURL.  I had to add an extra layer of `array(` to my `$data_string`, and also add `?commit=true` to the URL

```
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost:8983/solr/database/update?commit=true");

$data = array(
          "id" => "6686",
          "name" => array(
            "set" => "Brian")
          );

$data_string = json_encode(array($data));          

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

You think there'd be *some* sort of documentation on this... but I guess not.  I hope this helps someone else who's looking to do this same incredibly simple thing in the future....